# magento, add cron with config.xml file

Tags: xml, magento, cron

I am trying to add a cron to my Magento by adding this code in my  config.xml :

```
<crontab>
      <jobs>
        <kiwi_ordercanceller>
            <schedule>
                <cron_expr>*/5 * * * * </cron_expr>
            </schedule>
            <run>
                <model>ordercanceller/observer::cancelOrder</model>
            </run>
        </kiwi_ordercanceller>
  </jobs>
</crontab>
```

Calling this observer :

```
class Kiwi_OrderCanceller_Model_Observer {

    public function cancelOrder() { ...}
```

Still not workin !!

Can you help please

Thanks

Comment: where did you add this code? what else is in your extension so far?

Comment: i've made and edit, hope it helps

Comment: is your Magento shop-Cron running? * * * * *  php /var/www/vhosts/yourmagentosite/cron.php. If not the module crons are not scheduled and are not run

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11202463/how-to-setup-a-cron-job-in-magento-module