# How to set a cron job for a static block to run from date to date in Magento

Tags: magento, static, block

I have searched everywhere and found that it can be done via cron job enable/disable but I haven't been able to find how, or is there another method on how to display a static block from one date and be taken off at another date automatically? Thank you!

Comment: you have to disable static block using cron job?

Comment: @user5566 accept the answer so that it would be helpful to others

Answer (score 0):

You can create a static block and show it anywhere, and have a cron that enables/disables it at a specified date.

To do so, create a cron job like below.

```
<crontab>
    <jobs>
        <cronjob_name>
            <schedule><cron_expr>*/5 * * * *</cron_expr></schedule>
            <run><model>mymodule/my_model::functionName</model></run>
        </cronjob_name>
    </jobs>
</crontab>
```

Add the above code into one of your custom modules config.xml, changing mymodule for your module name, my_model for your model name and functionName for the model function you want to call.

Inside your `functionName` function, create a logic for enabling/disabling a static block that you created.

you can search more for creating/setting custom cron job and a logic to enable/disable a static block.

For more information check [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/6023/show-text-block-between-specified-dates), [here](http://fishpig.co.uk/magento/tutorials/cron-jobs/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11202463/how-to-setup-a-cron-job-in-magento-module)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code...

set cron in config.xml file in module

```
<global>
<crontab>
        <jobs>
            <[cronjob_name]>
                <schedule><cron_expr>0 0 * * *</cron_expr></schedule>
                <run><model>[Module]/observer::changeStatus</model></run>
            </[cronjob_name]>
        </jobs>
    </crontab>  
</global>
```

This cron run every midnight and change the static block status every time. to get more information about cronjob timing read these posts [first](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/19480/cron-job-asterisk-meaning/19482#19482) and [second](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/4838/how-are-dynamic-cronjobs-inserted-into-cron-schedule/4843#4843), which are answered by Magneto master. 
I am assume you have knowledge about observer class. call function in observer:

```
public function changeStatus() {

    $getStaticBlock = Mage::getModel('cms/block')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('identifier', 'my_block_id')->load();
    if($getStaticBlock->getData('is_active')){
        Mage::getModel('cms/block')->setData(array('is_active' => 0))->save();
    }else{
        Mage::getModel('cms/block')->setData(array('is_active' => 1))->save();
    }

}
```

Hope this code helps you. All the best.