# Magento autoupdate some tables

Tags: php, magento

I am a Magento developer and working on a Magento project, in which I need to execute some functions and update some table after a given time automatically.

How can I do this? If you have any idea, please share it with me.

Comment: A cron job would be suitable for this task

Answer (score 1):

If you need to update some table automatically then you can create a cron script and add cron job on cpanel manually or you can also use the magento cron job facility that it provides.

You can see this [StackOverflow Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11202463/how-to-setup-a-cron-job-in-magento-module) or this [Magento Tutorial](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/how_to_setup_a_cron_job)