# How to temporarily run file in app directory in Magento?

Tags: php, magento, http-status-code-401

I have file in app/code/local/MyModule/SalesXLSXExport/model/cron.php

This file is run every day with cron:

```
0 8,15 * * php -f /var/www/website/app/code/local/MyModule/SalesXLSXExport/model/observer.php >/dev/null 2>&1
```

and its working, but I would like to modify file and I want to run in browser this file, http://example.com/app/code/local/MyModule/SalesXLSXExport/model/cron.php but I have warning 401 forbidden. How to unblock this temporarily?

Comment: You probably have a .htaccess file located in the /app  directory. Have a look at it, and check if it Denys access to all :-)

Comment: Yes @Jonasm ! ;-) I have not noticed htaccess in /app directory... ;-) Thanks ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is invalid way to run module's cron.

You can refer following for basic module with cron.

[How to setup a cron job in Magento module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11202463/how-to-setup-a-cron-job-in-magento-module)